# Pronunciation of "jsfiddle"

Tags: pronunciation

English isn't my native language. I don't trust my pronunciation too much.

I don't know how to pronounce the domain name *jsfiddle.net*. There isn't any video about *jsfiddle*, so I can't learn the pronunciation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pronounce it as the single letters "j" and "s" and the word "fiddle": *JAY - ES - FID - uhl*.

Comment: fiddle's pronuncation is FID . so, what is uhl?

Comment: @Eray Alakese: No, the pronunciation of *fiddle* is *FID-uhl*. It's a two-syllable word.

Comment: @Jimi , like this ? : http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/fiddle

Comment: @Eray: absolutely! I was only trying to find a way to represent the pronunciation of the single letters *j* and *s*, and the word *fiddle*.

Comment: @Eray: no worries; you're welcome :)

Comment: Don't forget 'DOT - NET'

Comment: FWIW, ‘fiddle’ is pronounced /ˈfɪd(ə)l/. The absence of the optional schwa (ə) in the second syllable is probably more frequent than its presence, allowing the /l/ to function as a syllabic consonant.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say, since the "js" is an abbreviation for Javascript in this case (assuming you meant jsfiddle.net, not .com, which is an empty domain), you would say them as separate letters, then the word: "j-s-fiddle"

Answer (score 3):

I'll try and put it phonetically:

jay ess fid-uhl